# Proper technique when passing data between methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

If you have two methods in a model or controller and you want to pass a variable between methods e.g.

```
def foo
  @param = 2
  @test = 1
  callee
  #do something with @test
end

def callee
  @test += @param
end
```

Is it better to use instance variables to do this or regular variables like so

```
def foo
  param = 2
  test = 1
  test = callee(param, test)
  #do something with test
end

def callee(param, test)
  test += param
  test
end
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a definite answer to this question, it depends a lot on the context - the thing you need to ask is "which approach best demonstrates the intent of the code". You should definitely have tests for the model/controller class you are talking about.

As a very rough guideline:

The first approach is commonly seen when the method is part of the class's public API and it alters the internal state of instances of the class (although it may be the sign of a code smell if you have public methods chained as in your example.) This is probably going to be seen more often in a model object.

The second approach is usually seen when the method you are calling is a private convenience method that factors out some code duplication, or a method which does very specialised operations on the parameters and returns some result (in which case it should probably be factored out into a utility class.) This may be seen in model or controller objects.

If you are aiming for maintainable OO code, then the principles of SOLID design are very good guidelines - have a look at Uncle Bob's article about them here:

http://blog.objectmentor.com/articles/2009/02/12/getting-a-solid-start

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your needs. Also, prototype of the function that you are passing variables to is also important. If you want the method not to change any of the parameters without your permission, you should use your second implementation. But, if you trust the function, you can use first method. This is a big topic called as "call by reference" and "call by value". You can examine following link;

http://www.exforsys.com/tutorials/c-language/call-by-value-and-call-by-reference.html

Comment: This is ruby, not c: the call by reference / call by value distinction doesn't exist